# How to create a homogeneous random distribution of spheries in a cube?

Tags: random, statistics, distribution

I have a cube with side 'a'. '**n**' number of spheres need to be placed inside cube with uniform distribution. Perfectly uniform distribution is not possible with every value of **n**. So I want to get the coordinates of center of spheres when distribution of spheres is best for a particular number of particles (It might be a a random distribution of spheres).

Comment: Is this more of a math problem and should be on another site?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `n` would be and sphere radius? (assuming cube with 1x1x1 dimensions)

Comment: Let n be 500 and radius 0.01

Answer (score 0):

What you probably should looking into is Poisson spheres distribution - distribution of the points in the volume with minimum distance between them. Making minimum distance equal to 2R shall do the trick

Paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/26c3/490a9f2bdf8082d351639ff596f000f8e319.pdf

http://graphics.cs.kuleuven.be/publications/LD06PSD/index.html

PS It is generalization of the Poisson disk sampling in 3D

UPDATE

Looking into some of my records, I could propose another solution - use quasi-random Sobol sequences. There is a [theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378475406002382) by the man himself, which states that for unit hypercube minimum distance of `n` quasirandom points is equal to

0.5 sqrt(d) / n.

So for 3D unit cube, minimum distance between sampled points would we 0.5*1.732/n, or ~0.866/n. So if diameter of your sphere is equal or less than 0.866/n for `n` sampled points, this method might work for you. There are tons of Sobol sequences imlementations, in all languages, f.e. https://github.com/dendisuhubdy/sobol.